# Why the difference in rendering a form type?

Tags: css, symfony, webpack, bootstrap-5

I have two nearly identical versions of a small project. One we'll call 'webpack', the other we'll call 'retro'. The webpack verion uses `../app.scss/...@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` to serve styles (css). The retro version uses the ancient `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("css/bootstrap.min.css") }}"/>` method to serve css. `bootstrap.css` is 5.2.1 for each project. Source code in each (i.e., `../src` & `../template`) is identical.

What I cannot figure out is why a CheckboxType form field is rendered differently. The only difference I've found so far is in the timelines in Symfony's profiler. What's making the difference?

Edit: The difference between projects described here is not unique. There are distinct differences in rendering in all forms.

template snippet:

```
    <div class="col-6">
        {{ form_row(form.meal_type) }}
    </div>
```

`retro`:

[image]

`retro html`:

```
<div>
    <div id="meal_meal_type">
        <input type="radio" id="meal_meal_type_0" name="meal[meal_type]" required="required" value="Breakfast" checked="checked" />
        <label for="meal_meal_type_0" class="required">Breakfast</label>
        <input type="radio" id="meal_meal_type_1" name="meal[meal_type]" required="required" value="Lunch" />
        <label for="meal_meal_type_1" class="required">Lunch</label>
        <input type="radio" id="meal_meal_type_2" name="meal[meal_type]" required="required" value="Dinner" />
        <label for="meal_meal_type_2" class="required">Dinner</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

`webpack`:

[image]

`webpack html`:

```
<fieldset class="mb-3">
    <div id="meal_meal_type">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="radio" id="meal_meal_type_0" name="meal[meal_type]" required="required" class="form-check-input" value="Breakfast" checked="checked" />
            <label class="form-check-label required" for="meal_meal_type_0">Breakfast</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="radio" id="meal_meal_type_1" name="meal[meal_type]" required="required" class="form-check-input" value="Lunch" />
            <label class="form-check-label required" for="meal_meal_type_1">Lunch</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="radio" id="meal_meal_type_2" name="meal[meal_type]" required="required" class="form-check-input" value="Dinner" />
            <label class="form-check-label required" for="meal_meal_type_2">Dinner</label>
        </div>
    </div>        
</fieldset>
```

The only other difference I've found is in the timelines for each method.

`retro timeline`:

[image]

`webpack timeline`:

[image]

Comment: What does the rendered HTML output look like? The template code and screenshots don't really give a lot to go on here

Comment: The rendered HTML appears above, following the template snippet. In `retro`, the checkbox items appear glued together in a row. In `webpack`, the checkbox items are stacked.

Comment: No I am saying when you view the website and it does not look how you want it to, use the devtools and inspect the element and see what the actual final output HTML is. Obviously something is wrong or different if it is rendering that way which does not match what you expect. Something is either wrong, or something is not using bootstrap properly

Comment: did you build the webpack files? For me it is `yarn dev` but it might be something else for you. See the scripts section in your package.json file.

Comment: Despite the down vote (why?) I've added the HTML for the retro & webpack images. And yes, `webpack` was built with `yarn dev`.

Comment: I assume you have two different projects for this? The "retro" one definitely uses different templates. the thing you want to check for in both code bases is probably the [`form_theme` (doc)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html), which by default should not be bootstrap, but form_div_layout.html.twig (which seems to be used by your retro variant), the webpack variant seems to use the bootstrap form theme. might it be possible, that some config / code / magic sets this for your webpack version? in any case: you can set it explicitly in your retro version.

Comment: @Jakumi Thanks immensely for your comment! I'd missed this. Please post checking `../config/packages/twig.yaml` for `twig:form_themes`. In my case, `retro` was missing `['bootstrap_5_layout.html.twig']`.

Comment: glad I could help ;o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "retro html" and "webpack html" use different [form themes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html) which control how form elements are rendered.

The former uses `form_div_layout.html.twig` (the default) while the latter uses one of the desired bootstrap form themes.

You can either set form themes [*globally*](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#applying-themes-to-all-forms) in the `[project dir]/config/packages/twig.yaml` or [*individually*](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#applying-themes-to-single-forms) in the template itself (globally is usually preferred).